# Read all Lines of a cpp File with Fgets

Tags: c, fgets

in my simple impl. i want to read all lines of a cpp file

```
FILE * pFile;
    fopen_s(&pFile,"test.cpp","r+");
    if (pFile!=NULL)
    {
        fputs ("fopen example", pFile);
        char str [200];
        while (1) {
            if (fgets(str, 200, pFile) == NULL) break;
            puts(str);
        }   
        fclose (pFile);
    }
```

my text.cpp contains this:

```
Testline1
Testline2
Testline3
Testline4
```

as an output i get unreadable chars:

```
ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
```

what is wrong with my code?

my idea is to search for a special line of code, and edit it later on

Comment: What is it: `fputs ("fopen example", pFile);`? Why do you write into a file opened for reading only?

Comment: oh, i thought the r+ makes it readable and writable?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `r+` is both reading and writing. Still, it is a file and you should not write into the file you are going to read.

Comment: For making it writable you have to use w+. r+ means it will not create a new file is the file does not exist already.

Comment: As I recall, for text files you cannot follow writing directly by reading. There needs to be e.g. a seek in between. Also check the mode.

Comment: my idea is to search for a special line of code, and edit it later on

Comment: Can you read this file and write into another file or it should be done in the same file? reading and editing.

Comment: it has to be done in the same file...i just realizied that read-only works, but i want both reading and writing in  the same file.

Comment: FWIW, "r+" opens an existing file for read and write, "w+" opens an empty file for reading and writing. Any existing content is destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the file is open for updating, and you want to read<sup>2</sup> after writing you need to call fflush<sup>1</sup>. So call it after you write into the file here:

```
fputs ("fopen example", pFile);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.21.5.3 The fopen function 7)
However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek,
fsetpos, or rewind)

<sup>2</sup> Output is writing into the file, and input is reading the file.

Comment: rewind(pFile); does the job. thanks for the information @2501

Answer (score -2):

This code should achieve what you are trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *pFile;
    char buf[MAX_LINE];

    fopen_s(&pFile, "test.cpp", "r");

    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file for reading.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, MAX_LINE, pFile))
    {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Comment: my idea is to search for a special line of code, and edit it later on

Comment: And write the output to the same file?